# Replacing chars in only a part of a substring... will sed work?

Tags: bash, sed

I apologize in advance in case I have overlooked an available solution to my problem, but I've spent a few hours trying to figure this one out:

I have a logfile which is a mess [ not my fault T_T ] and I need to find lines that contain certain strings. Nice and simple up 'till this point. Once I've found them I need to replace every space between the words "Before" [ or String1 ] and "is" [ or String2 if you will ] with a different char [ underscore in my case ] . Nothing that comes before the "String1" or after "String2" may be affected.

To give you an idea what I'm supposed to do:

```
2012-08-27 00:14:55 1346019295409 Before Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer Curabitur In id urna ut. Ut massa ac commodo commodo rutrum ac sit neque ante pede. is 47 ms
```

should become:

```
2012-08-27 00:14:55 1346019295409 Before_Lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet_consectetuer_Curabitur_In_id_urna_ut._Ut_massa_ac_commodo_commodo_rutrum_ac_sit_neque_ante_pede._is 47 ms
```

Since the timestamp is different for almost every entry I've been thinking about trying to find some way how to set limits for sed, but no luck...

Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: "I've spent a few hours trying to figure this one out" - I understand you only have a hammer, but it's not the best tool to format a floopy disk... perl/python/php ? Looks like a 5 minute exercise.

Comment: To be honest I'm not that good with either of those and I was specifically asked to do it using what I posted above. I'm sure that I could make it in perl although I was told NOT to do that. Not sure why and I'm not asking, since my boss has been in a quite bad mood for the past two weeks since we're hunting for a performance problem in the application and our customers are becoming more and more impatient. But thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to ask when his mood gets a bit better n_n

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, I'll try to get it working / I seem to be encountering some typical newbie problems, but I'll fix that tomorrow./ I have to get some sleep tonight... It's already quite late here... to be more precise it's early in the morning =_=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ /_/4g;s/_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)$/ \1 \2/' file
```

Explanation:

- `s/ /_/4g` from the 4th space onwards replace space with `_`
- `s/_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)$/ \1 \2/'` replace the last two `_`'s with spaces.

An alternative method (perhaps more `_` safe):

```
sed 's/\( [^ ]*\)\{2\}$/\n&/;h;s/\n.*//;s/ /_/4g;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Explanation:

- `s/\( [^ ]*\)\{2\}$/\n&/` insert a linefeed before the last two spaces
- `h` copy the pattern space (PS) to the hold space (HS)
- `s/\n.*//` delete the pattern containing the last two spaces.
- `s/ /_/4g` replace all but the first four spaces with underscores in the PS.
- `G` append a newline followed by the contents of the HS to the PS.
- `s/\n.*\n//` delete the original first part of the string.

Comment: I bow, again, to the sed power of potong! GNU Sed rules ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for taking so long to say "Thank you very much. You helped me out of a very tight corner there."

Answer (score 2):

You can. Sed is Turing-complete, so you can do anything with it. This doesn't mean that sed is a good tool for the job: anything that doesn't map well to sed commands gets complicated really fast. If you insist on sed:

```
:a
s/\( Before .*\) \(.* is \)/\1_\2/
t a
s/ Before \(.*\) is / Before_\1_is /
s/ Before is / Before_is /
```

I recommend awk instead. The code is longer, but the logic isn't as headache-inducing.

```
match($0, / Before (.* )?is /) {
    prefix = substr($0, 1, RSTART + 6);
    middle = substr($0, RSTART + 7, RLENGTH - 10);
    suffix = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH - 3);
    gsub(/ /, " ", middle);
    $0 = prefix + middle + suffix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but with sed there are many versions, and you or may not have the latest version with all the cool features.

So a simple solution, given that you have the same format for each line, is to convert the first 3 spaces to tab chars, one at a time, (this may be a benefit for how you are using the data), and then convert all other spaces to '_' chars.

```
 sed '
    s/ /      /
    s/ /      /
    s/ /      /
    s/ /_/g' file > newFile
```

**edit** and, thanks to David Yaw for pointing out the required 2 spaces at the end of the line, I knew it couldn't be so easy :-). So.. you can add the following to the above script, again relying on the idea that there are a known number of substitutions you want to make; here we find the last 2 '_' chars and replace them back with spaces,

```
    '....
     s/\([^_][^_]*\)_\([^_][^_]*\)$/\1 \2/
     s/\([^_][^_]*\)_\([^_][^_]*\)$/\1 \2/' file > newFile
```

Newer sed's may not honor an escaped paren to capture a group; if the above doesn't work, try removing all 4 '\' chars from each line.

Note that of course, you have to do the right thing to get a tab char in the 2nd half of the s/srchTarg/replPat/' as the replacment Pattern. If you're using vi editor, Ctrl-V Ctrl-I (no space in between) will insert a tab char. And that, of course means a ControlV character, (hold down Ctrl key and press V), followed by a Ctrl I (hold down Ctrl key again, and press I). If you're copy pasting from a windows based editor, you can assume that the tab char is being converted to spaces, so you'll have to fight this on your own.

Also note that you could use some other char instead of tab, maybe ':' or '|', and as a final step, `s/|/ /g` to convert them back to spaces.

IHTH.

Comment: Scroll to the right in his sample text, he's got 2 words at the end that shouldn't get connected with underscores.

Comment: @DavidYaw : thanks, I missed that. I've edited my solution to solve that. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Perl

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/(?<=Before)(.*)(?=is)/$a=$1;$a=~s! !_!g; $a/e; print '
```

Invoked with -e Perl executes the statement enclosed in the single quotes. `(?<=)` is positive lookbehind. It matches everything after it. `(?=)` is a positve lookahead. It matches everything before it. `(.*)` matches the whole string between both and captures the match in $1. I use `s///` with the `e` modifier. This forces Perl to treat `/$a=$1;$a=~s! !_!g; $a` as Perl code and to executed it.

Simply try:

```
echo "2012-08-27 00:14:55 1346019295409 Before Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer Curabitur In id urna ut. Ut massa ac commodo commodo rutrum ac sit ne que ante petryde. is 47 ms" |
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/(?<=Before)(.*)(?=is)/$a=$1;$a=~s! !_!g; $a/e; print '
```